# shortauthor with apacite?

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

I'm working on a paper which requires citing a document with a corporate author, so an unwieldly name is something I'd like to avoid in my inline citations.

In order of preference, could I:

- define a short name to be used in all citations after the first; or
- define a short name to be used in citations (I'll manually track the first instance and provide the full name there)
- and maybe another option I haven't considered?

## MWE

`main.tex`

```
\documentclass[titlepage,a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{apacite}
\title{My Title}
\author{jimsug}

I would like to cite \cite{CORPAUTH} and have it appear as a short name, and output something like the below.

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{references}
```

`references.bib`

```
@booklet{CORPAUTH,
    author    = {{A Really Long Corporate Author Name}},
    title     = {A Booklet Title},
    year      = {2000},
    shortauthor = {ARLCAN}
}
```

---

> ### My Title
>
> #### jimsug
>
> I would like to cite (ARLCAN, 2000) and have it appear as a short name, and output something like the below.
>
> ### References
>
> A Really Long Corporate Author Name. (2000). *A booklet title*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you load the `apacite` package with the option `natbibapa`, you can make use of all of the `natbib` package's citation-related commands. Suppose that a usable abbreviation for "A Really Long Corporate Author Name" (in the entry with key `CORPAUTH`) was `RLCAN`. You could then issue the instruction

```
\defcitealias{CORPAUTH}{RLCAN}
```

in the preamble and cite the piece using either `\citetalias{CORPAUTH}` or `\citepalias{CORPAUTH}` in the body of the document. Of course, you're always free to display the full name using the "plain" `\citet` and `\citep` commands.

For more information on this subject, see section 2.6, "Citation Aliasing", of the [user guide](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf) of the `natbib` package as well as section 4.2 of the user guide of the `apacite` package.

Incidentally, if you have only one piece by `RLCAN`, it's generally not necessary to show the year along with the aliased author name when you cite the piece. The first time you cite the piece, though, I think it's good practice to show both the full name (including year) as well as the aliased name; for subsequent citation call-outs, the short alias suffices. See the example below for such a treatment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[titlepage,a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@booklet{CORPAUTH,
    author    = {{A Really Long Corporate Author Name}},
    title     = {A Booklet Title},
    year      = {2000},
    shortauthor = {ARLCAN}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\defcitealias{CORPAUTH}{RLCAN}

\begin{document}
As argued by \citet{CORPAUTH}---hereafter, \citetalias{CORPAUTH} for the sake of brevity---it is necessary to show that \dots 

\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```